# Creating multiple 'null' breeze entities and querying for only those entities

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application

Ok I asked this another way and have not yet seen a response so trying to simplify the question -

I want to create multiple entities and leave them in the 'added' entityState with Breeze.  Then I want to return only those objects and have them bound back to the parent through navigation property.

```
var createEntities = function (parent) {
    manager.createEntity('child', {parentId = parent.id()});
};
```

and then query for the parent and only return the created entities for an add view -

```
var getThoseDamnedEntities = function (parentObservable) {
        var query = EntityQuery.from('Parents')
            .where('id', '==', parentObservable.id())
            .expand('Child');

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (parentObservable) {
                parentObservable(data.results);
            }
            log('Retrieved [Parent] from remote data source',
                data, true);
        }
};
```

But I want to filter the Child results by entityState.Added so that I only return the new entities that have not yet been saved so that they can be modified before saving.  Any suggestions?

To expound on this - I could query the entity by type directly (ie. query = EntityQuery.from('Child').where()) and use a constructor to have a ko.computed property that is for 'Added' entities only but then I still can't figure out how to query those and bind them back to the parent object through navigation propertys (sorry if I screwed up the terminology there : ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I've understood your question, you actually have several approaches that you can take to this.

First, you should really only be querying the entityManager's local cache, because this is the only place that "Added" entities will be found.  They will not yet have been saved, ( hence still marked as 'Added').  You can do this by executing the inverse of the query you listed above **against the local cache only.**( I'm guessing about your entity type and property names here)

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Children')
        .where('parent_id', '==', parentObservable.id())
        .using(FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache).then(...)
```

which will return a promise, or you can do the same thing synchonously with

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Children')
        .where('parent_id', '==', parentObservable.id()) ;
var localChildren = myEntityManager.executeQueryLocally(query);
```

This will return every entity, in the local cache, that matches your filter, so if you only want the 'Added' ones, you will need to further filter the 'localParents', i.e.

```
var addedLocalChildren = localChildren.filter(function(p) {
   return p.entityAspect.entityState.isAdded();
})
```

The other approach, that might be even simpler is based on the idea that if you have already linked the parent entities to the children via a foreign key, then any entities in the entityManager cache will already have their navigation properties resolved. This means that you can simply do:

```
var children = parentObservable().child;  // 'children' might be a better name for this prop
var addedLocalChildren = children.filter(function(p) {
   return p.entityAspect.entityState.isAdded();
})
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Jay I have been trying this but p.entityAspect.isAdded() is not a valid function.  p.entityAspect.entityState.isAdded() works but setting this as a filter as you suggested is not returning the 'Added' entities.  I am looping through them and they are definitely EnumState 'Name = "Added"' but either isAdded() is returning false or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You are right it should have been p.entityAspect.entityState.isAdded() I just updated the post to correct this.  I also just confirmed that isAdded() is working correctly so I'm guessing that you have some other issue here.

Comment: Indeed the isAdded() function is returning true.  The problem was I removed the return inside of the filter :/